# Gradle: How do I stop Jetty if JMeter test failed

Tags: jetty, gradle, jmeter

How do I stop Jetty if JMeter test failed?
My Gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'jmeter'

jmeterRun {
    doFirst() {
        jettyRunWar.httpPort = 8080    // Port for test
        println "Starting Jetty on port:" + jettyRunWar.httpPort

        jettyRunWar.daemon = true
        jettyRunWar.execute()
    }
    doLast() {
        println "Stopping Jetty"

        jettyStopWar.stopPort = 8091   // Port for stop signal
        jettyStopWar.stopKey = 'stopKey'
        jettyStopWar.execute()
    }

    jmeterTestFiles = [
        file("src/test/jmeter/Tests.jmx")
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [finalizedBy](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#finalizedBy%28java.lang.Object...%29) to ensure that Jetty is stopped no matter whether JMeter runs successfully or fails.

```
jmeterRun {
    dependsOn jettyRunWar
    finalizedBy jettyStopWar
}
```

Comment: Your code produces error: Could not find property 'jettyStopWar' on task ':jmeterRun'

Comment: The standard task name provided by the Jetty plugin is `jettyStop`. You mention `jettyStopWar` above so I assumed you created another task with that name. If it doesn't exist it won't work of course.

Comment: I have the similar problem. Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103802/gradle-embedded-jetty-plugin-is-not-stopping-automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try the below settings:

In doFirst()

```
jettyRunWar.stopPort = 8090
jettyRunWar.stopKey = 'stopKey'
```

In doLast()

```
jettyStop.stopPort = 8090
jettyStop.stopKey = 'stopKey'
```

Not sure if it's a bug related to this [Link](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Stopping-Jetty-td5662999.html) or that you just need to specify a stopPort for jetty to be listening on.

I was having problems stopping jetty after running the jettyRunWar task in intelliJ but have those 4 settings in my build.gradle allowed me to stop jetty by running the jettyStop task.

Comment: I have the similar problem. Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103802/gradle-embedded-jetty-plugin-is-not-stopping-automatically