# Facing issue while running gradle clean build

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle 5 as my build tool for my Java application. I am getting below error while running gradle clean build.

`Could not set unknown property 'stopPort' for root project '1-SimpleServlet' of type org.gradle.api.Project`

PFA error image

[image]

Please find `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

stopPort = 8081 
stopKey = 'stopKey'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    providedCompile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

Pleas help me resolve this issue.

Comment: If you are using embedded `jetty`, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103802/gradle-embedded-jetty-plugin-is-not-stopping-automatically) gradle file as stopPort and stopKey should be part of some gradle `task`

Answer (score 0):

The `jetty` plugin has been deprecated with Gradle 3.0 and eventually been removed in Gradle 4.0 ([Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/release-notes.html), [Github Issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/735)). Since you're using Gradle 5, I suggest to have a look at the official [Building Java Web Applications](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-web-applications/) guide which uses the `gretty` plugin.

Example `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'org.gretty' version '3.0.1' 
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```